# IOS UItableview move cells touch point

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview and cells can be moved as I implemented the delegate method: `-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

The problem is that I have some buttons in the the right most area of each cell, and they can not be tapped as the whole area responds to to moving cell gesture. Is there any way to restrict the area for moving cell?
Thank you.

Comment: You could implement the touchesBegan and check if you hit the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation

NSInteger arrFlags[30];

and in ViewDidLoad{

intialize mutableArray for buttons

_arrButtons=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

add ur button into this array 

_bselect  = [ [ UIButton alloc ]  initWithFrame : CGRectMake (270, 15, 20, 20) ] ;

_bselect.tag = indexPath.row ;

[ _arrButtons  addObject : _bselect ] ;

 arrFlags [indexPath.row]  =  0;

in target u jst do what u want...

-(void) buttonTick:(id)sender{

UIButton *clicked=sender;

if (  arrFlags [ clicked.tag ] == 0) 
{

        [[ _arrButtons objectAtIndex:clicked.tag ] setBackgroundImage : [UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png" ] forState: UIControlStateNormal ];

        arrFlags[clicked.tag] = 1;

    }

else
{

}

// use this  indexpath.row  for  button  array  so  that  each  different  button  will be  selected  

place  ur  buttons  in  the  mutable  array  it  works 


}
```